# Running session failed due to tensors datatype and shape Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning

I tried to load the model and graph using the following methodology:

```
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
outputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
outputs = tf.cast(outputs,dtype=tf.float32)
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
sess  = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer()) 
if(tf.train.checkpoint_exists(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))):
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path))
    print(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path) + "Session Loaded for Testing")
```

It worked!...
But when I tried to run the session, I got the following error:

```
y_test_output= sess.run(outputs, feed_dict={X: x_test})
```

The error is:

```
Caused by op 'output', defined at:
  File "testing_reality.py", line 21, in <module>
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)+".meta")
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1674, in import_meta_graph
    meta_graph_or_file, clear_devices, import_scope, **kwargs)[0]
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1696, in _import_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\meta_graph.py", line 806, in import_scoped_meta_graph_with_return_elements
    return_elements=return_elements)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 442, in import_graph_def
    _ProcessNewOps(graph)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\importer.py", line 234, in _ProcessNewOps
    for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3440, in _add_new_tf_operations
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3440, in <listcomp>
    for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3299, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
    ret = Operation(c_op, self)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'output' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
         [[node output (defined at testing_reality.py:21)  = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,1], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Not getting what is the issue that caused this problem to me.
Please help me get the missing link.

I have checked:

```
>>> outputs
<tf.Tensor 'output:0' shape=(?, 1) dtype=float32>
```

Still could not understand the reason for the error.

I am using the latest version Tensorflow '1.12.0' on Windows 10 OS.

This is how the graph I am creating:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs],name="input")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_outputs],name="output")
layers = [tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=n_neurons,activation=tf.nn.relu6, use_peepholes = True,name="layer"+str(layer))
         for layer in range(n_layers)]
multi_layer_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(layers)
rnn_outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(multi_layer_cell, X, dtype=tf.float32)
stacked_rnn_outputs = tf.reshape(rnn_outputs, [-1, n_neurons]) 
stacked_outputs = tf.layers.dense(stacked_rnn_outputs, n_outputs)
outputs = tf.reshape(stacked_outputs, [-1, n_steps, n_outputs])
outputs = outputs[:,n_steps-1,:] # keep only last output of sequence

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - y)) # loss function = mean squared error 
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate) 
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Comment: I am not seeking debugging. I just wanna know what is the error coming if everything is getting loaded properly.

Comment: This does not seem to make a proper [mcve]. `tf.train.latest_checkpoint(model_path)` will load a computation graph that we don't have nor have enough information to reproduce. Moreover, the `x_test` in the line that's causing the error is not defined anywhere in the question.

Comment: It appears from the graph creation code that you wanted to retrieve a tensor for the inferred `outputs`, rather than the placeholder named `output`. You'll have to give it a unique operation name, so that it can be retrieved later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when you are trying to evaluate a node in the graph which is dependent on a value from a placeholder. Because of that, you are getting an error that states that you must feed a value for the placeholder. Have a look at this example:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
c = a + b
d = a

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(c.eval(feed_dict={a:1.0}))
# Error because in order to evaluate c we must have the value for b.

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(d.eval(feed_dict={a:1.0}))
# It works because d is not dependent on b.
```

Now, in your case, you should not execute the `outputs` placeholder. What you should execute is the operation you use to do predictions with your model, while feeding a value in the `X` placeholder (Assuming that you are using that one to feed the input in the model). On the other hand, I guess that you use the `output` placeholder to feed the labels while training, so there is no need to feed data in that placeholder.

Based on your latest update:

By doing: `outputs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')` you are loading the placeholder named output. You don't need that, you need the operation that slices the output. In the part of the code where the graph creation is, do:

```
outputs = tf.identity(outputs[:,n_steps-1,:], name="prediction")
```

Then, when loading the model, load these two tensors:

```
X = graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
prediction = graph.get_tensor_by_name('prediction:0')
```

Lastly, to get predictions on the input you want:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())   
sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={X: x_test})
```

Comment: I am running the session with the socket server. I have even tried to declare the outputs as global still getting the error.

Comment: That doesn't matter at all. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried using `outputs = graph.get_operation_by_name("output")` instead of tensors. I got error as the same. I don't know what mistake I am doing.

Comment: Can you include the graph creation in the question?

Comment: I have edited my question. please let me know if anything needed.

Comment: Check now. I assume it should be ok.

Comment: Let me know I guess that is the issue.

Comment: Thank you it worked...... I do not know why people here were unable to understand what I was looking for. You sir had understood.. You are really an intelligent person.